# Как свернуть КОНКРЕТНЫЙ кусок кода в VS code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Я хочу свернуть весь кусок кода JS в Vs code. Мне нужно свернуть код с //* Tabs до //* Timer[image: Вот пример кода]

Comment: Сделайте просто: выделите блоки в отдельные функции и оперируйте ими....вам же проще потом будет не в простыне кода а в отдельных функциях смотреть код

Comment: Используй регионы вместо комментариев.

Comment: @Qwertiy они разве не только для C#?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, они в js как-то через коммент пишутся. `// #region` или что-то такое. Я их не люблю, так что точно не помню. Ну и, возможно, надо ещё расширение на VS Code установить для их поддержки.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ничего там не надо - само работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй регионы:

```
// #region qs/qsa

export function qs(selector, parent = document) {
  return parent.querySelector(selector)
}

export function qsa(selector, parent = document) {
  return [...parent.querySelectorAll(selector)]
}

// #endregion
```

[image: скринвидео]